# Instantiating Child Controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have 1 Parent Controller and 1 View Controller.  I have successfully performed the `addChildViewController` and `transitionFromViewController` functions to leverage the Containment API provided by iPhone SDK.  Yet before I can actually pass view controllers to those functions I have a few questions

**Question 1**: In the ParentVC `ViewDidLoad` method must I instantiate all 4 child view controllers using the following

`UIViewController* child = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];`

**OR** `self.myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];`

**Question 2**: Assuming I do not instantiate all 4 child views initially in my `ViewDidLoad`... each time I add a new child using `addChildViewController` before I perform a transition using `transitionFromViewController`, am I required to instantiate the child VC I am desiring to add?

**Question 3**: Under the condition that the answers to Question 1 and/or Question 2 are 'Yes' what must be done about **memory management**.  For Question 1,  when navigating back to the parent VC from a child VC, it seems to mean that a new objects of the 4 child view controllers will be created, correct? When looking at Question 2, when transitions are made, which can be often, it seems to create a new copy of the child view controller objects each time.  In essence this app could become very bloated after some transitions between parent and child, and between child and child views.

**Question 4**: When `transitionFromViewController` is being called, what is happening in memory? What happens to the parent VC in a parent-child transition? What happens to the child VC in a child-child transition?

UPDATE: The following quote from [this particular tutorial](http://seanquinlan.com/2012/05/25/creating-a-container.html) seems to refer to some of my concerns (emphasis added):

> Note that `self.storyboard` isn’t set from an `init` call. At the moment,
>   there isn’t a great place to put this initialization code. One option
>   is to override `setStoryboard:` and another is `viewDidLoad`. The problem
>   with both options is that you **should guard the `addChildViewController:`
>   call to make sure that View Controllers aren’t instantiated twice.**

Comment: I'm not following what you're saying in that last point about setting the storyboard. The customary solution is to have a single storyboard that you identify in your target settings, and let iOS take care of everything for you. Generally you don't muck around with setting storyboards unless you're dealing with a huge project and you want to facilitate different teams working on different storyboards for purely logical reasons. But multiple storyboards (except, of course, one for iPhone and another for iPad) defeats much of the benefits of having storyboards in the first place.

Comment: Sorry failed to mention that the quote is taken directly from another website and is simply for context for the bold part of that quote...I am only using single storyboard that has been set in the target settings.

Comment: @Rob on that point, what is your opinion of that last part about twice instantiating? Is there a particular method you employ to keep track of instantiated objects and remove them?

Comment: On that quote, all they're saying is that you shouldn't be playing around with storyboards in initializer methods. But there's nothing new there: You shouldn't play around with _any_ user interface objects in controller initializer methods. You should always defer that until `viewDidLoad`. On that highlighted sentence, all they're saying is don't instantiate a view controller if you've already instantiated it and it's still around. Don't do `addChildViewController` if you've already added it and haven't removed it. Well, duh. Seems like an odd thing for them to dwell over, IMHO.

Comment: No, there's no special technique for keeping track of instantiated child controllers. It depends upon your particulars. But I just keep track of which one I'm on and when I want to go to a particular controller, I see if it's different than the one I'm on, and if so, I go through the "change child view controller" drill. If you want the old child deallocated, just make sure you don't have any strong references to it, so that when it's removed, it's deallocated. It's just memory management 101.

Comment: One final observation. That article you linked to is out of date. It says "there is no way to easily create your own Storyboard compatible Container View Controller." If using iOS 6, you can now represent the initial parent-child container relationship in the storyboard. But if you want iOS 5 backward compatibility, you have to do it as described in the article (or your refined, just-in-time technique).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, you don't need to instantiate all the children in the custom container view controller's `viewDidLoad` if you don't want. You can if you want, but you don't have to. You can instantiate them in a just-in-time manner if you would prefer.
2. Not only would you need to instantiate before `transitionFromViewController`, but obviously before `addChildController`, too.
3. If you choose to instantiate all of the view controllers up front, what member objects are created by the individual controllers is a function of how you handle it in those controllers, so it's impossible to answer that in the abstract. But this might be academic now that you know you don't have to instantiate all of the potential children at once.
4. `transitionFromViewController` will not affect the memory consumed by the controllers. What controls that would be the instantiating of the controller (and adding it to `addChildViewController`) and the subsequent `removeFromParentViewController` (assuming that's the last strong reference you have to the controller) that you might do in conjunction with `transitionFromViewController`.